# Can't connect to SQL Server using Trusted Connection from UWP-App

Tags: c#, sql-server, uwp

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server from an UWP-App using `Trusted_Connection=true` in Connectionstring. Connection.Open fails with error 18452 (not associated with a trusted sql server connection).
I can connect with SSMS using Windows-Authentication. Even from a .Net Core App the connection with the same connectionstring succeeds.

In UWP-Capabilities I've checked: `Enterprise Authentication, Internet (Client&Server), Private Networks` The Target version is Win10 version 1903, Min version is Win 10 Fall Creators Update

Here's a code snippet:

```
            using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Server=sql02;Database=Workdata_test_ad;Trusted_Connection=True"))
                await c.OpenAsync();
```

EDIT: connecting with explicit username and password works fine but is not the goal.

Comment: Hello, I verified using local SqlServer and it works fine. Did you choose Windows authentication, using a local account or a signed-in Microsoft account?

Answer (score 1):

Try server name as '.' `SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=pzdb01_test_ad;Trusted_Connection=True"))`

Comment: the sql server runs on a dedicated machine named sql02

Answer (score 0):

Our development sql server runs on Ubuntu, to which I'm not able to connect. the production server runs on Windows, to which i can connect from UWP-App.

Comment: Do you mean that the same connection string works fine to connect the Sql Server on Ubuntu if you are using the .net core application? And the same connection string works file to connect the Sql Server on Windows if you are using the UWP application? If so. could you please share your SQL Server version on Ubuntu in here? Thanks.

Comment: SELECT @@VERSION
2> GO
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU18) (KB4527377) - 14.0.3257.3 (X64)
        Nov 16 2019 01:14:50
        Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
        Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)